# Recursion with CTE not working for non-consecutive days but very slow with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, row-number

I have to calculate Exponential Moving Average for stock price. In the query I made the recursion based on the PriceDate. But this is actually not working since there are missing days (weekends, holidays). I have tried to do it with `ROW_NUMBER` but it is running really slow (more than 40 minutes before I cancel it).

I am looking for a way to do it with dates but to take into account that there are missing days. Or if it is with `ROW_NUMBER`, I will need a serious speed optimization:

```
DECLARE @timePeriod12 INT = 12
DECLARE @smoothingFactor12 FLOAT = 2.0/(@timePeriod12 + 1);


;WITH SMA AS
(
  -- calculate SMA for each row for the last N days
  SELECT @smoothingFactor12 as alpha
      --  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY PriceDate DESC) rownum
       , Ticker
       , PriceDate
       , ClosePrice
       , AVG(ClosePrice) OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY PriceDate ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sma
       
  FROM price.PriceHist
  WHERE PriceDate > (SELECT MAX(PriceDate) - 40 as PriceDate FROM price.PriceHist) --AND Ticker = 'AAPL'
  
),

EMA AS
(
    SELECT Ticker, PriceDate, ClosePrice, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 4), sma) AS ema 
      FROM SMA
            

     UNION ALL

     SELECT curr.Ticker, curr.PriceDate, curr.ClosePrice, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4), calc.ema) AS EMA 
       FROM EMA previous
      INNER
       JOIN SMA curr
         ON curr.PriceDate = previous.PriceDate + 1
        AND curr.Ticker = previous.Ticker
      CROSS
      APPLY (SELECT curr.alpha * curr.ClosePrice + (1 - curr.alpha) *  previous.ema AS ema) calc
      
)

INSERT INTO #tempEMA(Ticker, PriceDate, ClosePrice, EMA12)
SELECT * FROM EMA  

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

GO
```

The result from the query above clearly shows that it is very wrong to use PriceDate the way I use it.

[image]

Comment: How many records do you have in the table? Perhaps saving the output of SMA  to temp table (with appropriate indexes) and using said temp table in EMA calculation would help.

Comment: (1) `;` doesn't belong at the beginning of a line (2) a recursion needs a defined start, yours doesnt or is it intended? (3) try a temp table with ticker and rownum a index instead of cte SMA

Comment: Instead of `ROWS BETWEEN` maybe try `RANGE BETWEEN`? See https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/01/22/sql-server-windowing-functions-rows-vs-range/#:~:text=With%20the%20ROWS%20option%20you,and%20following%20the%20current%20row.&text=The%20RANGE%20option%20includes%20all,values%20as%20the%20current%20row.  Note this doesn't fix optimisation, but could help with weekends/days off/etc.

Comment: @Aツ I have created the CTE based on another one because I don't fully understand the concept.

Comment: @seanb `RANGE` supports only `UNBOUNDED and CURRENT ROW`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the advice from @Alex and moved SMA calculation in separate table. It worked great.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempSMA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempSMA

CREATE TABLE #tempSMA
(
Ticker VARCHAR(20), 
PriceDate DATETIME2, 
ClosePrice DECIMAL(17,5), 
sma DECIMAL(17,5),
rownum INT,     
);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO #tempSMA(Ticker, PriceDate, ClosePrice, sma, rownum)
SELECT
         Ticker
       , PriceDate
       , ClosePrice
       , AVG(ClosePrice) OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY PriceDate ROWS BETWEEN 26 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sma 
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY PriceDate) rownum
    FROM price.PriceHist
    WHERE PriceDate > (SELECT MAX(PriceDate) - 40 as PriceDate FROM price.PriceHist)
```

---

```
DECLARE @timePeriod12 INT = 12
DECLARE @smoothingFactor12 FLOAT = 2.0/(@timePeriod12 + 1);
```

---

```
;WITH SMA AS
(
  -- calculate SMA for each row for the last N days
  SELECT @smoothingFactor12 as alpha
       , rownum
       , Ticker
       , PriceDate
       , ClosePrice
       , sma
       
  FROM #tempSMA
  
),

EMA AS
(
    SELECT Ticker, PriceDate, ClosePrice, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 4), sma) AS ema, rownum 
    FROM SMA
    WHERE rownum = (SELECT MAX(rownum) / 2 FROM SMA)       

     UNION ALL

     SELECT curr.Ticker, curr.PriceDate, curr.ClosePrice, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4), calc.ema) AS EMA, curr.rownum 
       FROM EMA previous
      INNER
       JOIN SMA curr
         ON curr.rownum = previous.rownum + 1
        AND curr.Ticker = previous.Ticker
      CROSS
      APPLY (SELECT curr.alpha * curr.ClosePrice + (1 - curr.alpha) *  previous.ema AS ema) calc
      
)

INSERT INTO #tempEMA(Ticker, PriceDate, ClosePrice, EMA12)
SELECT Ticker, PRiceDate, ClosePrice, ema FROM EMA  

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

GO
```